# Create a startup script for running VNUML

Tags: startupscript

For creating the VNUML simulation containing specific number of devices we use 
vnumlparser.pl -t  -u root -w 100

But I am unable to run this using a start up scripts I have made in the location /etc/rcS.d/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I got it. For creating the VNUML simulation using the startup scripts I just needed to add the following :

**/usr/local/bin/vnumlparser.pl -t   -u root -w 100**

If this command line is used in a script file and placed in the /etc/rcS.d/ directory then the simulation will be created during the bootup of the PC.